# Objdump hello world call instructions

Tags: x86, objdump

This simple hello world:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Gives the following assembly in objdump:

```
    /helloworld.c:3
     804842c:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
     804842f:       68 f0 84 04 08          push   $0x80484f0
     8048434:       e8 b7 fe ff ff          call   80482f0 
     8048439:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
    /helloworld.c:4
     804843c:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
     804843f:       68 f0 84 04 08          push   $0x80484f0
     8048444:       e8 a7 fe ff ff          call   80482f0 
     8048449:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
```

- Why does the same call to puts have different hex codes (**b7** vs **a7**)?
- **e8** is the call part, but how is **b7 fe ff ff** translated to **80482f0**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call rel32` instruction: Call near, displacement relative to next instruction

The opcode for this instruction is `E8`, followed by the relative offset that is computed by the following equation: `destination address - address of next instruction`.

In this case, the relative offset of the first call is `80482f0 - 8048439 = FFFFFEB7`, and the relative offset of the second call is `80482f0 - 8048449 = FFFFFEA7`.

Answer (score 2):

The `E8` opcode belongs to a `CALL` instruction whose address is relative to the address of the `CALL` instruction itself. It uses `PC relative addressing`. So, what you see as the address of the function is actually the offset from the address of the next instruction to the address of the start of the `printf` function.

By the way, Intel uses little endian, so those offsets must be read as signed 32-bit integers `FFFFFEB7` and `FFFEA7` respectively. That means that the `printf` function is located in a lower address relative to your main program.

You can see also that the difference from these two offsets is the difference in bytes from one `CALL` instruction to the other one, as the second `CALL` will be farther from the beginning of `printf` than the first one.

```
0x8048444 - 0x8048434 = 16 (decimal)

0xFFFFFEB7 - 0xFFFFFEA7 = 16 (decimal)
```